# Implementing wordcount example and getting the following error

Tags: unix, hadoop, echo

I am trying to learn how to implement MapReduce in HADOOP.As a part of assignment I am trying to implement wordcount example using MapReduce.
For that I need to first create some data. I have implemented the following statement;

> echo "A long time ago in a galaxy far far away" > /home/cloudera/testfile1

Th error I am getting is the following:

bash: A long time ago in  a galaxy far far away: not a  valid command

Being new to UNIX, I am having difficulty in understanding what the error actually is. I will really appreciate if I can get some assistance here.

thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've shown. Did you type `echo` before the string?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna create some data using the echo command, please try this:

echo > " A long time ago in a galaxy far far away" > /home/cloudera/testfile1 and then you press Enter.

Explanation of my command line : type echo / space / > /space " /space the sentence/ " / space/ > / space /home/cloudera/testfile1 and press Enter

Once done, verify what directory you're in by using the : pwd command.

If you're in the cloudera directory, ....then type the ls command and press enter. It will list you the files inside that directory and you should be able to see the data you just created named as "testfile1".

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: As I commented above, I think that echo command written in the question should work and redirect to a file.